# Detecting gnosis safe through Walletconnect

Tags: gnosis-safe, web3-providers, gnosis, walletconnect

I am on a chain with a specific problem of not being able to estimate gas when Gnosis safe walletconnect dapp is used to connect to a dapp on this chain. So I require detection on whether the wallet that is using WalletConnect to connect to my dapp is Gnosis Safe (instead of, for example Trust Wallet). What methods / events I can listen to in order to distinguish between Gnosis Safe and other wallets that are using WalletConnect to connect to my dapp? Thanks.